# Enable Google App Indexing - how to prefix associated domain?

Tags: ios9, google-app-indexing

I would love to enable Google App Indexing in my iOS app; I followed [Google's tutorial](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/ios/app), but it only says

```
Add a com.apple.developer.associated-domains entitlement in XCode that lists each domain associated with your app.
```

Do I have to prefix my domain, e.g.

```
applinks:mydomain.com
```

?

Comment: your link to the Google's tutorial is broken

Comment: sorry, it's fixed now

Answer (score 1):

As far as currently documented supporting app indexing under iOS requires 2 steps:

**Support HTTP deep links in your mobile app as per Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH12-SW1)**

This involves creating the `apple-app-site-association` file that contains JSON data about the URLs that your app can handle, uploading the `apple-app-site-association` file to your HTTPS web server (to create a trust relationship between your site and the app) and adopting the UIApplicationDelegate methods.

**Integrate the App Indexing SDK as per Google's [documenation](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/ios/server)**

Install the `GoogleAppIndexing` pod and register your app in your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` as follows

```
[[GSDAppIndexing sharedInstance] registerApp:*your iTunes ID*];
```

**Additional notes**

It's important to remark that there must be a certain degree of coherence between the web and app content as stated in the Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/index.html)

> You can enable Google to crawl through your app content and present
>   your Android app as a destination to users through Google Search
>   results, **when that content corresponds to a web page that you own**.

If the crawler determines there's a significant difference between the 2 it might complain and give you a *Content mismatch* error in the search console. See the [crawl error FAQ](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6049161?hl=en).

Keep in mind that the app indexing seems to be still in a preliminary phase under iOS given that some information are available only for the Android platform, so ymmv.

**Further reference**

Check the WWDC video [*Seamless Linking to Your App*](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-509/) for a full implementation example. They talk about entitlements @ 23:20.

Comment: but what about the associated domain-stuff Google mentions in its tutorial? "Add a com.apple.developer.associated-domains entitlement in XCode that lists each domain associated with your app."

Comment: Google is just repeating what's in Apple's documentation (*If you’ve already followed the instructions to support universal links in your app, you can skip this section.*). Apple documentation is more exhaustive, follow that one.

Comment: I did, but even there nothing is mentioned regarding some prefix, but when adding an entry in the entitlements section, a default prefix (webcredentials) is provided. At another point I read something about applinks:

Comment: WWDC video shows a complete example, worth watching.

Comment: which one? 509 from 2015?

Comment: Yes. Check the **Further reference** paragraph in my updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94788/discussion-between-tomas-camin-and-swalkner).

Comment: Looks like `GoogleAppIndexing` library is not needed any more.